# adjacent_find does not detect last two elements

Tags: c++

Assume I have a vector containing the elements 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.
and I have a code like this.

it = std::adjacent_find (myvector.begin(), myvector.end());

this does not detect the last matching elements. Is this expected behavior ?

[Edit]Adding the code

```
int main () {
  int myints[] = {1,2,3,4,5,5};
  std::vector<int>::iterator it;
  std::vector<int> myvector (myints,myints+5);

  // using default comparison:
  it = std::adjacent_find (myvector.begin(), myvector.end());

  if (it!=myvector.end())
    std::cout << "the first pair of repeated elements are: " << *it << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates this?

Comment: Your code contradicts your assumption. Which one should we believe?

Comment: This kind of problem is quite common. When debugging problems like this, look at the values in the container: `for (int i = 0; i < myvector.size(); ++i) std::cout << my vector[i] << '\n';`. For this particular problem, the cause would have been immediately obvious; for other problems, it will usually provide a valuable clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> myvector (myints,myints+5);
```

You're missing one of your elements. This should be:

```
std::vector<int> myvector (myints,myints+6);
```

This is because the second argument to the constructor should point to one past the end of the sequence you want to copy.

Note that with C++11 you can just initialise your `std::vector` directly with:

```
std::vector<int> myvector = {1,2,3,4,5,5};
```

Comment: Or with any C++ version, use `myvector (myints,myints + sizeof(myints)/sizeof(myints[0]))` to outright remove this number-guessing.

Comment: @DrewDormann Or `std::vector<int> myvector(std::begin(myints), std::end(myints));` in C++11.